# how to account for digestion slowing down

Tags: calculus, integration

When you are properly hydrated, you are able to digest food at the maximum rate.

Your rate of digestion slows proportionally to your hydration, so that at 95% hydration, you digest at a rate of 95%.

Suppose your hydration is 100%. You eat food without water. This amount of food requires 10% of your body's water to digest.

This means that by the time you've finished digesting, you will be 90% hydrated.

How much longer will the food take to digest, compared to having eaten with the appropriate amount of water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(t)$ be the amount of food left in your stomach. It's derivative over time is negative (as you're digesting food) and proportional to your hydration level, $h(t)$:

$$\frac{dF}{dt} = - k \cdot h(t)  $$

where $k$ is some positive constant.

Your hydration has an initial level $h_0$ at $t = 0$, but decreases proportionally with the amount of food you have digested:

$$ h(t) = h_0 - l \cdot (F_0 - F(t))$$

where $l$ is a positive constant, and $F_0$ is the initial amount of food left in your stomach.

Filling the second equation in into the first yields a differential equation. Are you familiar with how to solve it from there?

Comment: Not quite, I'm woefully out of practice but I'll give it a try.  Thanks for the head-start, It's been many years since I've done anything like this